# Testcafe - Selecting an element in Shadowroot is not working

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selector, testcafe, shadow-dom

I have this website `https://www.storytel.com/sg/en/`where I am trying to click on the button (refer to the image) in the Subscription Component which resides in the Shadowroot. I have tried with the following codes but it didn't work. It will be great if someone can help. Thanks in advance.

```
test('Click inside shadowDOM', async t => {
  const shadowBtn = Selector(() => document.querySelector('storytel-subscription').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('*[data-testid="subscription-card-0-button"]'));

  await t        
      .click(shadowBtn);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Why the **\*** in the selector?

Comment: so it matches with any tags that has the property data-testid="subscription-card-0-button"

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug with processing elements in shadow dom. I suggest you create an issue in the TestCafe GitHub repository and describe your scenario there: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md